# Screen lag and flickering with several monitors using AMDGPU driver on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, amdgpu

I have just received my new Lenovo ThinkPad P14s gen 4. The CPU is an AMD Ryzen Pro 7840u, with the iGPU Radeon 780m.

I have installed a fresh Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS. Everything ran smoothly. But a second monitor wasn't usable, only the built-in screen was used.
Therefore, I installed the latest AMD GPU driver (23.40.2) following the docs. The installation process run withou any issue. When rebooting, a second monitor can now be used.

But strangely enough, when the external monitor is connected, the built-in screen starts flickering, or suffering of lag, and eventually becomes black and not used anymore.

This same driver worked correctly on an initial Ubuntu 22.04 install, but I had to revert to a Ubuntu 20.04 for other reasons.
I tried upgrading the linux kernel to several 6.x version instead of the default 5.15, but the problem persists.

Would you have any idea about how to solve this please?